# How can I optimize this mysql query please?

Tags: mysql, performance

Can anyone help me to optimize this query ? I can probably add some indexes and get only date from the modified (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) field ?

Thanks
Jeremy

```
SELECT a.providerName AS Assureur, b.insuranceType AS Produit, c.votedFor, c.votedFor2, c.email, c.comment, c.modified
FROM insuranceproviders AS a, insurancetypes AS b, insurancevotes AS c
WHERE a.id = c.providerId
AND b.id = c.insTypeId
```

Comment: You can probably add some indexes. The thing is - we can't guess your table structure

Comment: Can you explain your question in more detail table structure etc?

Comment: add index on c.providerId, b.id and as you said a modified date from a

Comment: have a look at the explain or describe keywords : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following join query looks better:

```
SELECT a.providerName AS Assureur, b.insuranceType AS Produit,
    c.votedFor, c.votedFor2, c.email, c.comment, c.modified
FROM insuranceproviders AS a
    INNER JOIN insurancetypes AS b ON a.id = c.providerID
    INNER JOIN  insurancevotes AS c ON b.id = c.insTypeId
```

and You should add following INDEX:

```
ALTER TABLE insuranceproviders ADD INDEX(id);
ALTER TABLE insurancetypes ADD INDEX (providerID, insTypeId);
ALTER TABLE insurancevotes ADD INDEX(insTypeId);
```

Comment: The first line is probably `ALTER TABLE insurancevotes ADD INDEX (providerID, insTypeId);` ?

Comment: @Jeremy Yes. absolutely!

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below:
[Here I am doing Left join as i dont know the table structure instead you can also have inner join]

```
SELECT a.providerName AS Assureur, b.insuranceType AS Produit, c.votedFor, c.votedFor2, c.email, c.comment, c.modified
FROM insurancevotes AS c
LEFT JOIN insuranceproviders AS a ON   a.id = c.providerId
LEFT JOIN insurancetypes AS b ON b.id = c.insTypeId
```

Answer (score 0):

use indexes for a.id, c.providerId, b.id, c.id(if there is), c.insTypeId